# How to handle if an invalid Id is passed to the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently doing a project in MVC 3 and can't figure out if a user passes an invalid id (let's say 23233), how can i display a message to the user that item with this id does not exist?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, please let us know or retag appropriately. MVC is a general architectural model applicable in other technologies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is ASP.NET, use `Find()` in your `DbSet` to find a user with that `Id`. If the result is `null`, use something like `RedirectToAction()` to send the user to a page explaining the problem.

The VS scaffolding system already does something similar, except it returns an `HttpNotFound()` instead in the automatically generated code. You can use its logic as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

first.
You are create a checker method for id.

```
 public bool idChecker(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            double numeric = -1;
            bool retval = double.TryParse(id, out numeric);
            return retval;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and you will use idChecker method.

```
        public ActionResult YourActionMethod(string id)
    {
        if (!idChecker(id))
            return Content("Invalid ID"); // or your code
        else
            return View(); // or your code.
    }
```